# nginx name-based multiple virtual hosts not working

Tags: docker, nginx, vps

I have an nginx docker running with a virtual host that reverse-proxies to a django setup in the same docker bridge (this works). I am trying to add a second virtual host that would serve static html content from nginx itself. I am trying to follow examples on the web, but have not been able to get it to work. Hoping someone can spot what I am doing wrong.

In the files below, I have changed the DNS names for anonymity. Both abcde.wxyz.org and abcd.defgh.org resolve to the same IP, and name resolution works fine.
(a) Accessing https://abcd.defgh.org/ (i.e., the proxy) works fine.
(b) Accessing http://abcde.wxyz.org/ (the static webpage), I get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(c) Accessing https://abcde.wxyz.org/ gets me to (a), which should not happen either.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

In the /etc/nginx/conf.d/ directory there is one file (called 'django.conf') that looks like:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name abcd.defgh.org;
  access_log  /var/www/logs/abcd.defgh.org.log;
  error_log  /var/www/logs/abcd.defgh.org.log error;
  root /var/www/abcd.defgh.org/public_html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}


server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name abcde.wxyz.org;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/localhost.key;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;


  location / {
    proxy_pass http://web:8000;
    }
}
```

'web' is resolved by the docker name service, and works.

I can't seem to get access logs or error logs from the nginx docker to be able to troubleshoot further.

Comment: I find names you are using very confusing. It's usual to use names like `example.com` and `example.org`. You say "https://abcd.defgh.org/ (i.e., the proxy) works fine", but the `proxy_pass` statement in your configuration has `server_name abcde.wxyz.org`. You only have one `server` listening on port 443, so **all** `https` requests will be handled by that block, irrespective of the value of `server_name`.

Comment: Thanks Richard. You are right, I messed up the anonymization of my DNS names. Will use better ones in the future. It turned out to be that I was not allowing port 80 traffic to the docker, hence the nginx wasn't getting the port 80 traffic at all.

Answer (score 0):

False alarm. Turned out to be a docker environment problem. The docker was setup with only port 443 being forwarded to it, and not port 80.